# How do I conditionally format cells based on an indirect formula that references "moving" cells

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, conditional-formatting

Stackoverflow community,

I'm using Excel '10.  I currently have an indirect formula that references 4 cells to determine the x,y coordinates for a sum range.

Formula: =IFERROR(SUM(INDIRECT(G27&G26):INDIRECT(H27&H26)),"No Records")

How do I use conditional formatting to highlight the cells that the formula is summing?

Comment: Can you give some examples of what G27, G26, H27, and H26 are?

Comment: G27 and G26 would be the cell coordinates - Ex. G27 = C and G26 = 12; H27 = E and H26 = 9.  So the formula above would sum(C12:E9).  My question is how to use conditional formatting to highlight cells C12:E9 based on the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a new conditional format for a given cell range which compares the current row and column numbers to the indirect reference cells.

**R1C1 style**

```
=IF(AND(ROW(RC)>=R26C7,ROW(RC)<=R26C8,COLUMN(RC)>=R27C7,COLUMN(RC)<=R27C8),1,0)
```

`=ROW(RC)` will give you the current row number of the local cell

`=COLUMN(RC)` will give you the current column number of the local cell.

**A1 Style**

```
=IF(AND(ROW(A1)>=$G$26,ROW(A1)<=$H$26,COLUMN(A1)>=COLUMN(INDIRECT($G$27&$G$26)),COLUMN(A1)<=COLUMN(INDIRECT($H$27&$H$26))),1,0)
```

Since we are using A1 style, you must convert your indirect column reference letters to numbers using `COLUMN(INDIRECT())`.

In this case, 'A1' is shown in the formula because that is the first cell in the range that I am conditionally formatting. You should change this to whatever the first cell in your range is.

Comment: Hi Brino, Although i've never seen this formula before, I am making sense of it...slowly - When I paste the formula into the rule, Excel states that there was an error - There is little other information as to the specific error.

Comment: `CHAR(64+COLUMN(A1))` this will fail for 2 or 3 letter column names like 'AA'

Comment: Fortunately, my columns don't go past H. It's not accurately selecting all of the cells.  I should note that the highlightable range is from C8:G12.  How does this affect your formula?  I believe a tweak is still needed. Thank you

Comment: Sorry for that, I have made the correction. In your case if you want the formatting only to apply to C8:G12, you would highlight your cells, then apply a conditional format using a formula =IF(AND(ROW(C8)>=$G$26,ROW(C8)<=$H$26,AND(COLUMN(C8)>=COLUMN(INDIRECT($G$27&$G$26)),COLUMN(C8)<=COLUMN(INDIRECT($H$27&$H$26)))),1,0)

Comment: @user3964075 You are correct. I was converting the wrong value. The column function will convert all 1,2 or 3 column letter names to their appropriate value. EX: COLUMN(AAA4) = 703

Comment: @BRINO The formula is still creating an error.  I'm following the row portion of your formula, but the column portion makes less sense to me. The column values are in G27 and H27.  The row values are in G26 and H26, which you call out in the row portion of the formula.  As a reminder, I'm referencing the columns by their column letter (e.g. "G", "C").

Comment: @Justin This formula is working for me. The point of the formula is to check each cell and see if its row is >= G26 and <= H26, and to check the column number and see if it is >=G27 and <= H27. Since you are using A1 style (ie: 'A1' instead of 'R1C1'), your column values in G27 and H27 are letters, not numbers, so we first convert them to references, then get the column number using `=COLUMN(INDIRECT($G$27&$G$2‌​6))'. Try following the steps again, clear your existing conditional formats, then highlight C8:G12, then add the formula for your conditional format.

Comment: @Brino thank you for all of your support - that works.  It's so bizarre, although the formulas are exactly the same, there is something that produces an error when i copy and paste the formula from this site.

Comment: @Justin when you copy from the comments, you also copy the whitespace characters including line breaks. StackOverflow actually adds some characters on the linewrap of my comment right after ($G$27&$G$2‌​, which do not show up in the excel formula input. The original answer does copy and paste correctly.  If you are happy with the answer please mark it as accepted.